# Custom cursor scaling with windows accessibility settings

Tags: c++, qt, qt6

I have implemented 32x32 custom cursors with bitmaps using the following approach (in Qt 6.1.1):

```
this->setCursor(QCursor(QBitmap(":/Cursors/arrow_up.bmp"), QBitmap(":/Cursors/arrow_up_mask.bmp"), 3, 0));
```

The cursors work as expected if the Windows display setting for size of apps and text is set to 100%. However, if the size of apps and text setting is increased, Qt scales up the custom cursors accordingly and they become pixelated (e.g. if 150% is selected, Qt increases the size of the custom cursors by 50%).

Is there a way to prevent Qt from resizing the custom cursors? Alternatively, is there a way to know what the user has selected in Windows for the size of apps and text, so that I can provide cursors at the correct resolution?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
QCursor cursor = QCursor(QIcon(":/Cursors/arrow_up.bmp").pixmap(32, 32), 0, 0);
this->setCursor(cursor);
```

means that use `QIcon` instead of `QBitmap` and set its size by `pixmap(32, 32)`.

Another things that may help you :

put this line in your main.cpp file :

```
QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
```

Read [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html) Document . As I understand setting `AA_EnableHighDpiScaling` flag Enables high-DPI scaling in Qt on supported platforms (see also High DPI Displays). Supported platforms are X11, Windows and Android. Enabling makes Qt scale the main (device independent) coordinate system according to display scale factors provided by the operating system. This corresponds to setting the QT_AUTO_SCREEN​_SCALE_FACTOR environment variable to 1.

Comment: Thanks Parisa. Unfortunately, Qt still scales up the cursor when using that approach (although, it is slightly less pixelated than directly using the bitmaps).

Comment: your welcome , Try using the Cursor icon `SVG` file instead of `bmp` file .

Comment: I tried it with an svg file instead, and it still looks a bit blurry when Qt scales it up. It seems like Qt sets the size to 32x32 and then upscales it from there vs normal icons where you can provide a higher resolution image and Qt scales it down to fit the specified icon size.

Comment: So , well I think , it's better to have multiple icons . In different size and resolution and set some condition that if change screen resolution icons change, i think in OS like windows or Linux  do this.

Comment: I agree. That seems like the best solution. However, it seems like Qt assumes the size you provide is based on 100% text size setting on Windows (i.e. pixelDeviceRatio = 1) and then scales the cursor up regardless. So even if I provide a 64x64 cursor for pixelDeviceRatio  = 2, Qt will take that and scale it up again. Any ideas on how to stop Qt from applying the scale factor?

Comment: Well , did this happens in Released mode?  I asked because sometimes it's different . between debug mode and Released mode .

Comment: @karl_simmons  I Edited My answer , I hope that this helps you .Put `QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);` in main.cpp file

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but on Qt6, I get a warning that high DPI scaling is enabled by default. Is there another way to set QT_AUTO_SCREEN​_SCALE_FACTOR = 1?

Comment: I don't use Qt 6 , because it's not stable. But I test that flag in Qt5.14 .